# resx files mystically changed by visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I edit a windows form in vb.net, those resx files get altered seemingly randomly.

Why?

[image]

Comment: That is the binary data for the image, produced by BinaryFormatter and encoded with Convert.ToBase64String().  To make deserializing the data safe, BinaryFormatter embeds the type of the data, the fully qualified assembly name of the .NET type.  Which includes the type name, the version number and the binary key token.  So if the form got started on an old version of .NET, like 2.0.0.0 and converted to 4.0.0.0 or from the legacy framework to .NET5+ then, yes, that type name changes.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: I never alter those images @HansPassant

Comment: Just editing the form is enough to get the designer to update this data.

Comment: But how is the data getting different every time then?

Comment: @AndersLindén Hans has just explained it: There's some data in that binary "blob" that is added by the serializer (and actually irrelevant for the image data itself). So the simple answer is: Don't care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data is an image, created by using a `BinaryFormatter` followed by a Base-64-encoding. If you add an image to a form using the windows forms designer, that's encoded like this in the resx file. The `BinaryFormatter` includes information about the full type being serialized, including the version of the assembly containing the type, in the serialized stream. Therefore the data changes when the data is deserialized and serialized again with a new version of the runtime.

It's (typically) not a problem to read data from an older version, since the types are compatible. So even though this is confusing, there is no impact on the expected functionality. The actual image won't be different and the "problem" can be ignored.